# Blender Overrides Smoke Cache Files To Original On Startup

Tags: smoke-simulation, cache

I wanted to create a reverse smoke simulation.In other words, the smoke moves in reverse as the time goes on.
What I did was first create an external library and then,I  rename all the blender smoke cache files in reverse 
In other words, frame[1] became frame[250],frame[2] became [249]and vice versa. I did this for all the cache files it worked!

But here's where it went wrong...
Whenever I save the project, reopen blender and play the animation, blender overrides all the cache files that I renamed and sends them back to their original naming.In other words, all my renaming was just a waste...So, the smoke no longer plays in reverse as the animation plays, but goes to the original or normal movement of smoke.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You could try making then cache file read only, or create a copy of the corrected files and copy them over when ever they get regenerated. I have not seen a setting to stop it happening though. Can you not reverse the entire animation after rendering forwards?

Comment: well I could but that's the thing. It means that I have to reanimate the camera movement ALL OVER. I just feel that blender should have a setting in the smoke simulator to make which allows you to control the movement and flow of the smoke. With that, we can animate it in reverse and all. I am currently trying out that method though. Rendering everything in reverse.. I had to reanimate the camera movement and change a LOTTA keyframes.Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Bake the smoke domain cache first. This tells Blender to calculate the smoke and store it in the cache and to effectively mark that cache as 'read only' until yo tell it to 'free' it. This will mean that Blender will not attempt re-run the smoke simulation, leaving your manipulated (reversed) cache as it is.

[image: Bake Smoke]

Comment: thank you Sir/Madam..But I did that already please. I even did that before I came here to ask for help.I baked the simulation and renamed all the cache files in reverse. But the issue still persisted. I will try your method again. See the results this time. Thank you..  :)